# How to accomplish pagination with HBase through a C# application?

Tags: c#, api, rest, hbase

I have seen examples of achieving pagination with HBase through console queries.

Using C#, most-likely accessing HBase through RESTful calls, how can this be accomplished?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, you will need to use Scanner in RESTful calls and keep on doing next in your scanner calls.
Here is the documentation: https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Stargate

Alternatively, i would suggest you to use Thrift. I think, that might provide you better feature set.

Also, I stumbled upon .NET api for HBase from Microsoft: https://github.com/hdinsight/hbase-sdk-for-net